# Rolling Average in Python with inf values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to match this final output, calculating the moving average (3) of Count,

Expected Output

```
     Classification     Name     Count     MA3
0    Fruits             Apple    inf       NaN
1    Fruits             Apple    inf       NaN
2    Fruits             Apple    inf       NaN
3    Fruits             Apple    inf       NaN
4    Fruits             Apple    5.0       5.0
5    Fruits             Apple    6.0       6.5
6    Fruits             Apple    7.0       6.0
7    Fruits             Apple    8.0       7.0
8    Veg                Broc     10.0      NaN
9    Veg                Broc     11.0      NaN
10   Veg                Broc     12.0      11.0
```

But the python .rolling code does not take into account of the inf values, is there any work around on this?

```
df['MA3'] = df.groupby(['Classification', 'Name'])['Count'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3,3).mean())
```

Current Output

```
     Classification     Name     Count     MA3
0    Fruits             Apple    inf       NaN
1    Fruits             Apple    inf       NaN
2    Fruits             Apple    inf       NaN
3    Fruits             Apple    inf       NaN
4    Fruits             Apple    5.0       NaN
5    Fruits             Apple    6.0       NaN
6    Fruits             Apple    7.0       6.0
7    Fruits             Apple    8.0       7.0
8    Veg                Broc     10.0      NaN
9    Veg                Broc     11.0      NaN
10   Veg                Broc     12.0      11.0
```

Comment: Hi Jing. Well, what would you _like_ that output to be, given that `inf` is indeed the correct value for a moving average that includes infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a series S that contains the calculations replacing `inf` by `nan` and set min_periods=1. Then, creates a mask for the rows that need to be modified, that is, the ones that are one or two positions after an `inf`

```py
df['MA3'] = df.groupby(['Classification', 'Name'])['Count'].transform(lambda x: x.replace(np.inf, np.nan).rolling(3, min_periods=3).mean())
S = df.groupby(['Classification', 'Name'])['Count'].transform(lambda x: x.replace(np.inf, np.nan).rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean())
mask = df['Count'].lt(np.inf) & df['MA3'].isnull() & (df['Count'].shift(1).eq(np.inf) | df['Count'].shift(2).eq(np.inf))
df.loc[mask, 'MA3'] = S.loc[mask]
```